# React Native PureComponent Rendering

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6

Reading [When to Use Component or PureComponent](https://codeburst.io/when-to-use-component-or-purecomponent-a60cfad01a81) in the **Don’t bind values in functions in render** section it mentions that instead of doing 
`<CommentItem likeComment={() => this.likeComment(user.id)} />` you should do `<CommentItem likeComment={this.likeComment} userID={user.id} />` and then have:

```
class CommentItem extends PureComponent {
  ...
  handleLike() {
    this.props.likeComment(this.props.userID)
  }
  ...
}
```

Because when the parent’s render method is called, a new function (with a new reference) is created to be passed to `likeComment` which will cause  all the children to re-render, even if the data itself is all the same.

I am a little confused by how arrow functions bind and am wondering if the following example will also result in bad behavior

```
_keyExtractor = (item, index) => String(index);

render() {
    return (
        <FlatList
            ...
            keyExtractor={this._keyExtractor}
            ...>
        </FlatList>
    );
}
```

As `FlatList` is a PureComponent (I believe), will this definition of `_keyExtractor` result in the `FlatList` being re-rendered if it's container parent is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `reference` that he is referning to here is the object reference 
as you know `{} === {}` is `false`

in javaScript functions are objects, so every time the render is called children would have to rerender because you passed a new function.

```
(x => x) === (x => x) // false.
```

the last example you provided is fine because the function will keep its reference at all time.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this code helps you bro:

```
export default class PureComponent extends Component {
shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
    return shallowCompare(this, nextProps, nextState);
  }
}
```

You can even return this:

```
return !isEqual(this.props, nextProps) || !isEqual(this.state, nextState);
```

Note:

```
import {isEqual} from 'lodash';
import shallowCompare from 'react-addons-shallow-compare';
```

Dont forget these imports.

This component will serve as a perfect PureComponent.